# Why is it keep on asking when I input correctly?

Tags: python, while-loop, nested

```
def main():

 month = 0
 date = 0
 year = 0
 date = [month, date, year]
 user = input("Enter according to mm/dd/yy:")
 user = user.split('/')
 month = user[0]
 date = user[1]
 year = user[2]
 while int(month) > 12  or int(month) < 1 :
    print("Month is incorrect.")
    user = input("Enter according to mm/dd/yy:")
 while int(date) > 31 or int(date) < 0:
    print("Date is incorrect.")
    user = input("Enter according to mm/dd/yy:")
 while int(year) > 15 or int(year) < 15:
    print("Year is incorrect.")
    user = input("Enter according to mm/dd/yy:")
```

I keep on getting Month incorrect when it's correct. Please help. I'm trying to get the user's input to match the correct form of mm/dd/yy. And I'm trying to convert yy -> 2015. Please help.

Comment: Please put a language tag on this question.

Comment: You don't update `month`, `date` or `year`...

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in your code.
Suppose if my input is "15/30/15", then it says incorrect month and tries to fetch user input in format "mm/dd/yy", but now the user is not spliting based on '\', so the while loop keeps running till the user[0] is assigned to new month. This error occurs for incorrect date and year as well.
To fix it just call the user input function and split the user inside the while loop itself.

Comment: Hi! Is it possible if you could write out the code for me to see? I'm still new at python so it's a little confusing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just like [@nneonneo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551977/why-is-it-keep-on-asking-when-i-input-correctly#comment47255304_29551977)'s comment pointed out, you forgot to update `month`, `date` and `year`.

This would cause your while-loop to only use the very first recorded values for these fields.

Your current problem can be solved simply by adding this code at the end of each while-loop:

```
 user = input("Enter according to mm/dd/yy:")
 month,date,year = user.split('/')
```

As you might have guessed, the above is a nicer implementation of this piece of code from your question:

```
 user = input("Enter according to mm/dd/yy:")
 user = user.split('/')
 month = user[0]
 date = user[1]
 year = user[2]
```

This would reduce the clutter in every while-loop.

Also, assuming your current indentation is correct, your code won't give you your desired output because it is not accounting for the case where the user starts with all 3 invalid fields: `month`, `date` and `year`. If the user enters a correct month first, he would be able to enter an invalid month later on and still produce an output.

Instead of using three while loops, you should use an `if-elif-else` block. This would ensure you get a proper answer:

```
def main():

    user = input("Enter according to mm/dd/yy:")
    month,date,year = user.split('/')

    while True:

        if int(month) > 12  or int(month) < 1 :
            print("Month is incorrect.")
        elif int(date) > 31 or int(date) < 0:
            print("Date is incorrect.")
        elif int(year) > 15 or int(year) < 15:
            print("Year is incorrect.")
        else:
            break
        user = input("Enter according to mm/dd/yy:")
        month,date,year = user.split('/')

main()
```

Comment: I tried this a while ago. But it gave the error of the year. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '/'

Comment: @lastdancestop You probably didn't `split()` the input correctly, that error only shows up if you try to use the `int()` method on an input that cannot be converted to type `int`. For example, you might have done `int(month)` when month was equal to `"32/"` or something